# how to deal with fasttext library to build a text classifier?

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, text-classification, fasttext

I am doing sentiment analysis on twitter dataset in Arabic , and finished the phase of preprocessing on data .I want to use fasttext tool to build a classifier but I do not know how , I need some clear steps to upload my data and build the classifier , any help ?

Answer (score 2):

I think the official tutorial can be useful for you: https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/supervised-tutorial.html. It explains the steps to follow.

I give you some details about data preparation (the tutorial explains it superficially)

- First of all, you have to prepare your dataset in this way:

__label__firstlabel __label__secondlabel example text line

__label__thirdlabel other example text line

__label__firstlabel __label__fourthlabel another example text line

Each line of your dataset must start with one or more labels (to feed the classifier), then the text line.

- Then, you have to split the dataset in train set and validation set

The example in the tutorial is the following:

> head -n 12404 cooking.stackexchange.txt > cooking.train
>   
>  tail -n 3000 cooking.stackexchange.txt > cooking.valid

- Then you can train your classifier, test it and make it better...

**An idea: if your corpus is not very big, you can improve the performance of your model using pretrained vectors, provided by Fasttext (option pretrainedVectors: https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/options.html)**

For more informations on Fasttext, i suggest the book fastText Quick Start Guide
by Joydeep Bhattacharjee (https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/fasttext-quick-start/9781789130997/)

Comment: is there any problem if i put the label of the sentence at the right side instead of left side as Arabic sentence start from right side ??

Comment: I have another question please , what if I wanted to build CNN deep learning model after this step to make it learn from data ,is there any good sites that explain these steps clearly ?

Comment: I think the labels must be in the left side.

Comment: If you follow the tutorial, you use Fasttext as a classifier: under hood, it is a neural network itself.

If you want to use Fasttext only as a word embedding and build a deep learning model on it, the steps are different:
read https://www.kaggle.com/vsmolyakov/keras-cnn-with-fasttext-embeddings